password_hash() cannot recognize my password correctly
I know I registered " 1 " as the password but as I check the password stored in the DB using password_verify(), it can't be recognized correctly. Can someone point out what I did wrong? If I use md5() or sha1() it works fine but I know, this is a more secure implementation of hashing password.
handleForms.php
if (isset($_POST['registerUserBtn'])) {

    $username = sanitizeInput($_POST['username']);
    $first_name = sanitizeInput($_POST['first_name']);
    $last_name = sanitizeInput($_POST['last_name']);
    $password = $_POST['password'];
    $confirm_password = $_POST['confirm_password'];

    if (!empty($username) && !empty($first_name) && !empty($last_name) && !empty($password) && !empty($confirm_password)) {

        if ($password == $confirm_password) {

            $insertQuery = insertNewUser($pdo, $username, $first_name, 
                $last_name, password_hash($_POST['password'], PASSWORD_DEFAULT));

            if ($insertQuery) {
                header("Location: ../login.php");
            }
            else {
                header("Location: ../register.php");
            }

        }

        else {
            $_SESSION['message'] = "Please make sure that both passwords are equal";
            header("Location: ../register.php");
        }
    }

    else {
        $_SESSION['message'] = "Please make sure that all input fields are not empty!";
        header("Location: ../register.php");
    }
}

if (isset($_POST['loginUserBtn'])) {

    $username = sanitizeInput($_POST['username']);
    $password = $_POST['password'];

    if (!empty($username) && !empty($password)) {

        $loginQuery = loginUser($pdo, $username, $password);
        $userIDFromDB = $loginQuery['user_id']; 
        $usernameFromDB = $loginQuery['username']; 
        $passwordFromDB = $loginQuery['password'];

        echo "WHAT YOU TYPED: " . $password . "<br>";
        echo "FROM THE DB: " . $passwordFromDB . "<br>";

        if (password_verify($password, $passwordFromDB)) {
            echo "YES EQUAL";
        }

        else {
            echo "NOT EQUAL";
        }
    
    }

    else {
        $_SESSION['message'] = "Please make sure the input fields 
        are not empty for the login!";
        header("Location: ../login.php");
    }
 
}

models.php
function insertNewUser($pdo, $username, $first_name, $last_name, $password) {

    $checkUserSql = "SELECT * FROM user_accounts WHERE username = ?";
    $checkUserSqlStmt = $pdo->prepare($checkUserSql);
    $checkUserSqlStmt->execute([$username]);

    if ($checkUserSqlStmt->rowCount() == 0) {

        $sql = "INSERT INTO user_accounts (username, first_name, last_name, password) VALUES(?,?,?,?)";
        $stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
        $executeQuery = $stmt->execute([$username, $first_name, $last_name, $password]);

        if ($executeQuery) {
            $_SESSION['message'] = "User successfully inserted";
            return true;
        }

        else {
            $_SESSION['message'] = "An error occured from the query";
        }

    }
    else {
        $_SESSION['message'] = "User already exists";
    }

    
}

function loginUser($pdo, $username, $password) {

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM user_accounts WHERE username=?";
    $stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->execute([$username]); 

    if ($stmt->rowCount() == 1) {
        $userInfoRow = $stmt->fetch();
        return $userInfoRow;
    }

}


What is the size of the password field in the database? By the far the most common mistake in this situation is storing the hashed password in a field which is too small for it, meaning it gets truncated when it's saved. The password_hash documentation mentions the minimum size requirement very clearly. (I can't see any obvious mistakes in the way you're using PHP to store, retrieve and verify the password, btw.)

P.S. As an aside, what does your sanitizeInput function do? I will bet you a substantial sum that it's cargo-cult nonsense you've found online which will do nothing except potentially harm your data. What threats are you trying to "sanitize" against in this context exactly? You're already parameterising the query which takes care of SQL injection risks, and the code here does nothing else with the input data, so there's no obvious reason to do any other processing on it at this point. You're welcome to show us the code of that function and we can check it.
